# developer tools used in programming

Tags: python

I am a pretty recent developer..
but I have a single monitor (big enough) but it is so annoying that every now and then I first use the text editor to write the code and then go to terminal to execute and debug
I was wondering if there is any developer tools where I can like use half screen for that note pad and the other half for terminal.. so that I dont have to shuffle back and forth between the terminal and the text-editor...
Something like, when this software is running... then notepad and terminal just freezes in that half screen and when i close this software I can minimize and turn to normal mode.
If not it would be cool thing to have. :D
THanks

Comment: Half screen gedit and half screen a terminal perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you say "terminal" do you mean a python console or a real system terminal?**

If it is the first case, then most if not all python IDE I have ever used do have that functionality built in: gedit, eclipse, geany, SPE, just to mention a few.

If it is the second case, some IDE like gedit do have a plugin for that, but in general what you should probably use is another *window manager* (namely a *tiling* window manager). No idea on how the situation looks like on Microsoft / Apple OS's, but under GNU/Linux you have a plethora of different tiled window managers. Two that I tried and liked are [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) and [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/).

HTH!

Comment: great. :) thanks a lot. actually I am also on ubuntu.. so works for me.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use *ViM* in split window mode, edit your script on the left side and start ConqueTerm (use *:ConqueTerm bash*) on the right side. Now you can code and execute Python code in the same terminal window at the same time using a superior text editor ;-)

*Disclaimer: Of course this only helps if you are familiar with ViM already.*

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing in Python - have a look at PyCharm. It's a clone of IntelliJ IDEA, tailored for python development, written in Java, so work on any platform. If you like it, it also doesn't cost a whole truckload.

That's for the easy and money-based way. More complex ways - you can use a text editor that allows running your scripts, upload to webservers, whatnot. It pretty much depends on the stuff you're developing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There are many editors... and IDE's that will allow you to run your code from directly within the editor / IDE enviroment

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems like the easiest way is to simply manually resize the windows and place them where you want them. Also, a handy tool in general is the Python IDLE, where you can code in the Python window and simply have it run in the shell by pressing F5.